# Return List of Lists of 3 tuples using recursion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm a Haskell newb. I'm trying to write a recursive function that takes the argument:

```
([(Bool, Bool, Bool)], Int, Int)
```

and return a List of Lists of 3-tuples:

```
[[(Bool, Bool, Bool)]]
```

so for example a call of

```
recursFunction ([(True, False, False), (False, True, False)], 25, 25)
```

should return

```
[[(True, False, False)],[(False,True,False)]]
```

so far I have

```
recursFunction :: ([(Bool, Bool, Bool)], Int, Int) -> [[(Bool, Bool, Bool)]]
recursFunction ([], y, z) = [[]]
```

I'm stuck and I'm not sure how to proceed or use recursion for this function.

Comment: Why is this wrapped in an extra list? Why `[[(Bool, Bool, Bool)]]` and not just `[(Bool, Bool, Bool)]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem because I'm returning multiple lists inside of a list

Comment: But your  tuple can only contain *one* list, so there is no reason here to wrap it in another list: the *inner* list will always be a singleton list (containing one element), so as a result you have a type that gives *less* constraints.

Comment: What's the purpose of the function? The example you gave just returns the same that was passed as parameter so I don't see where is the recursion and how the two integer parameters affect the function.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use recursion. The list of 3-tuples is stored in the first parameter, so we can obtain it with:

```
recursFunction :: ([(Bool, Bool, Bool)], Int, Int) -> [[(Bool, Bool, Bool)]]
recursFunction (l, _,_) = ...
```

here `l` will be the list of booleans, so `l` has type `l :: [(Bool, Bool, Bool)]`. If the output type is just `[(Bool, Bool, Bool)]`, we can thus return:

```
recursFunction :: ([(Bool, Bool, Bool)], Int, Int) -> [(Bool, Bool, Bool)]
recursFunction (l, _,_) = l
```

otherwise we can wrap each 3-tuple in another list, for example with [**`pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:pure). Here we `map` every element of the list (such element has type `(Bool, Bool, Bool)` in a *singleton* list, so:

```
recursFunction :: ([(Bool, Bool, Bool)], Int, Int) -> [[(Bool, Bool, Bool)]]
recursFunction (l, _,_) = map pure l
```

But personally I do not see any benefit from this: since now it looks as if every element of the result is a list, and that list can - given the definition - contain zero, one or more elements. But since we know for sure it contains *exactly* one element, it is thus better *not* to wrap it in a list.